# How do I skip an iteration in a loop if it throws an error?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, error-handling, cmd

I am working in Windows 7 cmd.  I wrote a couple of lines of code to copy certain files from a pretty big directory tree.  Here is the code:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir "L:\Level1\Level2\Level3\\\*." /ad /b') do robocopy "L:\Level1\Level2\Level\%a\Level5\Level6\Level7" "c:\Destination\%a" /E /V /R:1 /W:1 /MT:32 /SEC
```

Basically, this goes into all Level4 folders (within Level3) and copies the files found in the rest of the directory.

The issue I am experiencing is that some of my Level4 folders don't actually have the Level5/Level6/Level7 path. So every time the loop gets to one of these folders, it crashes the loop.

I'd like to modify the above code so that I the loop will simply skip any folders that are causing errors, and continue on to the next.

I am running this on cmd command line. Not batch.

I know very little to no cmd code. Therefore, I would appreciate if your answer explains clearly what the syntax of the modifications should be. I know the solution is related to "errorlevel" but I am clueless as to how to implement.

Comment: Just tried this pattern and been unable to reproduce your issue. In my case, the loop wasn't interrupted, it just moved on to the next item.

Answer (score 3):

Check the `robocopy` source folder presence using `if exist` as follows:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir "L:\Level1\Level2\Level3\\\*." /ad /b') do if exist "L:\Level1\Level2\Level\%a\Level5\Level6\Level7\nul" robocopy "L:\Level1\Level2\Level\%a\Level5\Level6\Level7" "c:\Destination\%a" /E /V /R:1 /W:1 /MT:32 /SEC
```

In more readable form:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir "L:\Level1\Level2\Level3\\\*." /ad /b') do ^
  if exist "L:\Level1\Level2\Level\%a\Level5\Level6\Level7\nul" ^
    robocopy "L:\Level1\Level2\Level\%a\Level5\Level6\Level7" ^
             "c:\Destination\%a" /E /V /R:1 /W:1 /MT:32 /SEC
```

Note the `folder\nul` condition.

`NUL` is a file-like object which exists in any *existing* folder...

Comment: You probably meant `…\Level3\%a\…` instead of `…\Level\%a\…`. On another note, `if exist folder\ dosomething` would work as well.